# проблема с MediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android, аудио, mediaplayer, музыка

```
public void soundPlay(MediaPlayer sound) {
    if (sound.isPlaying())
    sound.pause();
    else
    {   sound.start();
      sound.setLooping(true); } }


public void soundPlay2(MediaPlayer sound) {
    if (sound.isPlaying()) {
        sound.pause();
    }
    }
```

Здравствуйте, я только учусь программированию. Сейчас работаю над музыкой в приложение, использую самый простой код для музыки в андроид приложениях, но теперь его недостаточно. Мне нужно чтобы:

1. Музыка не накладывалась друг на друга если пользователь нажимает назад и обратно заходит (т.к. музыка будет фоном).
2. При сворачивание приложения музыка останавливалась.
3. При звонке музыка останавливалась.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это всё реализовать либо ссылку где я могу найти ответы на свои вопросы. Желательно на русском языке. Все мои попытки найти ответы в гугле не увенчались успехом, во всех уроках что я нашел по музыке нет ответов именно на мои потребности.

Comment: Все три вопроса связаны с Activity Lifecycle. Изучайте тему и поймете как применить к вашей задаче. Готовых рецептов нет. https://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/lifecycle.php

Comment: Спасибо @Eugene Krivenja , теперь я понимаю куда копать